# determine server is window or linux on VPS

Tags: vps

I have access to a virtual private server , The OS is windows Server 2008,
How can I determine what OS is installed on the Real server?
is there any command prompt code or something to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use compiler predefined macros to detect the operating system type.

```
#if !defined(_WIN32)
```